# Testing authenticated routes with JWT fails using Mocha + supertest + passport

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mocha.js, passport.js

I'm trying to test authenticated routes in Mocha but the user created in `before` or `beforeEach` hooks does not persist.

In `test.js`

```
const should = require('chai').should(),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    request = require('supertest'),
    app = require('../../../../server'),
    agent = request.agent(app),
    AdminUser = require('../../../models/AdminUser');

var credentials = {
    username: 'admin',
    password: 'password'
};

var admin = new AdminUser(credentials);

describe('authenticated routes', function() {
     before(function (done) {
         admin.save(function (err) {
             if (err) done(err);

             agent.post('/api/authenticate')
             .send(credentials)
             .end(function (err, res) {
                 if (err) done(err);
                 jwtToken = res.body.token;
                 done();
             });
         });
     });

    it('should get content with 200', function (done) {
        agent.get('/api/content')
        .set('Authorization', 'JWT ' + jwtToken)
        .expect(200)
        .end((err, res) => {
            if (err) return done(err);
            done();
        });
    });

    after(function (done) {
        AdminUser.remove().exec();
        done();
    })
});
```

I have tried using `beforeEach` and cleaning up in `afterEach`, the initial post to `/api/authenticate` returns a `200` successfully, a token is received but when trying to authenticate with the token, it gets a `400`. This is due to `AdminUser` not found.

In passport strategy, I have:

```
module.exports = function (passport) {
    passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, function(jwtPayload, done) {
        AdminUser.findOne({ username: jwtPayload.username }, function (err, user) {
            if (err) { return done(err); }
            if (!user) {
                return done(null, false, { message: 'Bad token.' });
            }
            return done(null, user);
        });
    }));
};
```

`AdminUser` is always `null` regardless of where I save the user. Only works when I nest the callbacks but that negates the use of `before` or `beforeEach`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use Authorization header with the **Bearer** authentication scheme:

```js
.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + jwtToken)
```